# Is Angular 2 AOT compilation and tree shaking with rollup slow?

Tags: angular, typescript, rollup, aot, lite-server

I'm going through the [angular 2 deployment documentation on AOT](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) and it recommends making copies of the JIT compilation files and maintaining the AOT and JIT files side by side.

Ideally I would be able to develop with the AOT / Rollup compilation configuration only.  The documentation mentions that this will soon be possible.  Just wondering whether anyone has any experience with this?  Is it still slow relative to JIT compilation or can a reasonably fast development experience be had with real time AOT compilation and tree shaking?

Comment: Reading through this new tutorial (https://www.sitepoint.com/ultimate-angular-cli-reference/) and it looks like this may have been fleshed out better with the new angular-cli

Comment: Just try 4.0 and see if it suits you. For me it's still very slow for development with Webpack, so maintaining JIT and AOT configurations together makes sense.